# Map char pointer to in-memory file with file descriptor

Tags: c++, c

I try to map a char * to an in-memory FILE* with fmemopen. 
I just found out that fmemopen will not give me a file descriptor. 
Is there a way to get an in-memory FILE with FD?

```
char * data = ... data ...;
FILE *fid = fmemopen(data, 172, "r");

int fd =  fileno(fid);
if(fd < 0)
    std::cout << "BAD" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "GOOD" << std::endl;
```

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes I was reading this. I just posted my example to make clear what I want. My question is "Is there a way to get an in-memory FILE with FD?". It doesn't has to be with fmemopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look and see if `shm_open()` in conjunction with `fdopen()` does what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    FILE *f = NULL;
    int fd = 0, n = 0;
    char buffer[6] = "hello";

    fd = shm_open("myfile", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if(fd<0) {
       printf("failed to shm_open\n");
       exit(1);
    }
    f = fdopen(fd,"w+");
    if(!f) {
       printf("failed to fdopen\n");
       exit(1);
    }
    n = fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), f);
    printf("wrote %d bytes", n);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome.  If it is acceptable, awarding the answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[`fopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) is based on the `open` *system call* and therefore has a corresponding file descriptor.

[`fmemopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) on the other side is a pure *library* implementation and doesn't need a system file descriptor. See also the [`NOTES`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html#NOTES) section on `fileno`.